# How to validate form in AngularJs while using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have form in angularjs, i was validate an email field. 
The validation works great, but when i add another email field the validation works on all the items. But I only want the first field to be validate as required.

```
<form novalidate name="myForm">
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="addNewChoice('email')">
    <i class="fa fa-at"></i> Add Email
  </button>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div data-ng-repeat="email in emails">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" ng-class="{
                                       'has-error'   :isInputInvalid(myForm.email1),
                                       'has-success' : isInputValid(myForm.email1)
                                        }">
        <label for="email{{ $index + 1}}">Email {{ $index + 1}}</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email{{ $index + 1}}" ng-model="formModel.emails[$index + 1]" id="email{{ $index + 1}}" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.email1.$error.required && myForm.email1.$dirty">Required</span>
        <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.email1.$error.email">Email not valid!</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/y302r7tL/25/)

Comment: You are the correct track. You just have to change other *myForm.email1* to *myForm.email{{ $index + 1}}*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do something for only first item in a list rendered by `ng-repeat`, you can simply make use of [`$first`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

So, instead of having just `required`, we can utilize `ng-required` like this:

```
ng-required="{{$first}}"
```

And, using `$first` at all the things used, we can get rid of validation for emails other than first!

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y302r7tL/26/)

**EDIT**: What I understood from the question is that you don't need validations for emails other than first. If your concern was that it says invalid for second even when first is invalid, check [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y302r7tL/27/) which has individual validation for all emails entered.

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan yeah, that's better! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove "&& myForm.email1.$dirty" in "Required span"

Comment: still not working. I update the fiddle [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/y302r7tL/25/)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove first element out of n**g-repeat** loop as it is required field and add then new choice email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ng-if="$first"**

**Try this**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('appMy', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log("hguy");
  $scope.formModel = {};

  $scope.emails = [{
    id: 'email1'
  }];

  $scope.isInputValid = function(input) {

    return input.$dirty && input.$valid;
  }

  $scope.isInputInvalid = function(input) {
    return input.$dirty && input.$invalid;
  }
  
  $scope.addNewChoice = function(val) {


     var newItemNo2 = $scope.emails.length+1;
     $scope.emails.push({'id':'email'+newItemNo2});
   
   
  };

});
```

```css
.help-block {
  color: #b34848;
}

.has-error label {
  color: #a94442;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="appMy">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form novalidate name="myForm">
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="addNewChoice()">
        <i class="fa fa-at"></i> Add Email
      </button>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div data-ng-repeat="email in emails">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12" ng-class="{
                               'has-error'   :isInputInvalid(myForm.email1),
                               'has-success' : isInputValid(myForm.email1)
                             }">
            <label for="email{{ $index + 1}}">Email {{ $index + 1}}</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email{{ $index + 1}}" ng-model="formModel.emails[$index + 1]" id="email{{ $index + 1}}" placeholder="Enter email" required>
        <span ng-if="$first" class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.email1.$touched && myForm.email1.$invalid">Required</span>
            <span class="help-block" ng-show="myForm.email{{ $index + 1}}.$error.email">Email not valid!</span>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```